# Create 2 virtual camera devices streaming the same images one actual webcam does

Tags: virtual, webcam, gstreamer

I would like to use the images of one webcam in two different systems that require exclusive access to the video device simultaneously. Therefore I created two virtual cameras with v4l2loopback, one for each of the systems, and now I am trying to stream the data from the actual webcam to both virtual cameras. I tried to use GStreamer, but it only allows me to stream the data to one single virtual camera. If I try to stream to the other one also, I end up with my original problem of the webcam being already busy. I can't figure out a way to solve this problem, help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought I haven’t actually tried it, suppose you have a webcam attached and its /dev/video0, now create two virtual devices using v4l2loopback say /dev/video1 & /dev/video2 and now create a gstreamer pipeline with a tee element which outputs to 2 v4l2sink's /dev/video1 and /dev/video2.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot! I didn't know the tee element and somehow it didn't come up while googleing. What now worked for me was setting up 2 v4l2loopback devices and then running gstreamer with:
'gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1' ! tee name=t ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1 t. ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video2

gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1' ! xvimagesink'

Comment: This is no big deal, but now that there is `gst-launch-1.0` available, the command should be `gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! "video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1" ! tee name=t ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1 t. ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video2`